# Creating a label on IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to make it so when a button is clicked this a label comes up and will eventually animate. I made a start but this label does not show up at all. The CGRect coords are correct I am using a 3 page wide scroll view. Anyway, here is the code

```
UILabel *plusSymbol = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(987, 349, 330, 326))];
plusSymbol.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%f", applesPerClick];
```

Comment: did you add the label as a subview?

Comment: I assume not, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the label to the button.

```
UIButton *btn;
UILabel *label;

[btn addSubview:label];
```

Comment: More likely to the buttons superview, but the principle is the same.

Comment: well, you are right but when you will add any object, it should ideally be placed on top if we go by the order of addition.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a view or button or anything from code you have to add to the screen:

```
UILabel *plusSymbol = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(987, 349, 330, 326))];
plusSymbol.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%f", applesPerClick];
[self.view addSubview:plusSymbol];




//[yourParentView addSubview:plusSymbol];
```

If you want to add on the Button

```
[yourButton addSubview:plusSymbol];
```

But be careful because the frame is in your parentView. if your button is 100*100 then you have to modify the `plusSymbol.frame`.  `plusSymbol.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);`